# How to Troubleshoot Strange CPU Spikes on Linode

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu, cpu-usage, linode

My Linode sever running Ubuntu 12.04 have been experiencing strange MySQL database connection errors occasionally.

Looking at the CPU graph provided by Linode, I noticed that CPU usage gets rather high. The server is hosting a low traffic Wordpress site and a low traffic phpBB3.

[image]
[image]

**Question:** How do I find how what's causing the high CPU load, and how do I reduce it?

Answer (score 1):

CPU Utilization: Monitor how your Linode’s CPU cores are being utilized. Note that each of your Linode’s CPU cores is capable of 100% utilization, which means you could see this graph spike well over 100%, depending on your Linode plan size.

Extracted from https://www.linode.com/docs/uptime/monitoring-and-maintaining-your-server

That means If you have 6 cores, you can have up to 600% CPU utilization.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've done this by setting up an alert using [monit](http://mmonit.com) to email me when there is a problem, then I can log in and check the log files for any weird activity, and check the process stack to see what might be out of control.